# Node.js en el lado del cliente y del servidor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Tengo entendido que con Node.js puedo usar código javascript para ejecutar acciones tanto del lado del servidor como del cliente. Una parte del código que intento implementar corre perfectamente en node.js:

```
var jre = require('node-jre');
var output = jre.spawnSync(["E:/proyectosJavaScript/prueba1/holaMundo.jar"], 
"hola.holaMundo", ["parametro"], { encoding: 'utf-8' })
.stdout.trim();
console.log(output);
```

Este código ejecuta un .jar externo de java (Hola Mundo) y almacena la respuesta en la variable output. El problema es cuando intento pegar el valor de esa variable en un html con el siguiente código:

```
var titulo = document.getElementById("P1t1");
titulo.innerHTML=`${output}`;
```

el navegador me devuelve:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at "nombreDelScript"
```

Por otra parte cuando ejecuto el código completo en la consola cmd obtengo:

```
 ReferenceError: document is not defined
 at Object.<anonymous> (E:\proyectosJavaScript\prueba1\libreto.js:125:14)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
 at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
 at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
 at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Entiendo que me falta algo para vincular ambos mundos, pero he navegado bastante buscándolo y no lo encuentro. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola, si pudieras aclarar cómo deseas consumir la API, entonces te podría dar una respuesta. Actualmente tal como está formulada la pregunta no es específica y habría muchas formas de implementar una solución. Por otro lado, te aclaro que Node.js está diseñado exclusivamente para trabajar de lado del servidor y por lo tanto no existe un DOM para manipular. Si lo que deseas es ejecutar código de Node.js en el navegador tendrías que usar librerías adicionales en tu página, por ejemplo: [Require.js](https://requirejs.org). Saludos

Comment: Complementando mi comentario anterior, si lo que deseas es probar tu aplicación Node.js sin implementar un servidor con `express` o `sockets` tienes la opción de usar un librería de Node.js llamada [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), la cual te permite hacer pruebas del comportamiento de tu aplicación. Es cuestión que decidas lo que más te conviene. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Contreras. Gracias por tu predisposición. Quiero hacer un bot para interactuar con binance que es un exchange de criptomonedas (compra y venta de criptomonedas).  Necesito hacer peticiones a la API de binance (GET y POST) y quería usar las herramientas gráficas que disponibles para cualquier página web. Simplemente algún gráfico de evolución de precios y alguno que otro menú desplegable. Nada muy complejo pero que sea dinámico (es decir que se actualice con cada petición a la API), no necesariamente necesito que sea en el navegador. Gracias